# How to use density argument to obtain inequality?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Let $(X, \|\cdot \|)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach spaces. Assume that $T$ is a linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ ($T:X\to Y$). Assume that  $D\subset X$ is dense in $X.$  The operator $T$ satisfies the inequality $\|Tf\|_{Y} \leq \|f\|_{X}$ for all $f\in D.$

> Question: Can we expect $\|Tf\|_{Y}\leq \|f\|_{X}$ for all $f\in X$?

Edit: This [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator#Further_properties) tells that: "A common procedure for defining a bounded linear operator between two given Banach spaces is as follows. First, define a linear operator on a dense subset of its domain, such that it is locally bounded. Then, extend the operator by continuity to a continuous linear operator on the whole domain." Can anybody elaborate this or any reference for the details?

Comment: T is continuous right?

Comment: i would think that the answer to the original question is no.
But the situation in your edit is very different, because the operator is only defined on a dense set, and not (yet) on $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. There are linear operators $T$ that are bounded on a dense subspace, but not bounded.

See [this example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28415/unbounded-operator-bounded-in-a-dense-subset) which has $Y=\mathbb R$, but is not constructive.

For your edit:
Here, the operator is not given on $X$, but only a dense subset $D$. Therefore we can choose which values $T$ will have on the points $X\setminus D$

You have to do following steps (i will still leave out some details):

1. define $T f= \lim T f_n$ where $f_n\in D$ such that $f_n\to f$ for all $f\in X$.
2. in order to justify **1.**, show that the limit actually exists (hint: use Cauchy sequences).
3. in order to justify **1.**, show that the definition is independent of the chosen sequence $f_n$.
4. show that the resulting operator $T:X\to Y$ is bounded.