# Density argument for a densely bounded operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a dense domain $D$, i.e. There exists a positive constant $C$ such that
$$||Ax||_H\leq C||x||_H, x \in D.$$
My question is: What assumtpions should $A$ satsisfies so that the boundedness can be extended on $H$?.
For me it is straightforward but I have some doubts about that.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How should I interpret "For me it is straightforward but I have some doubts about that"?

Comment: The doubt came from this question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361381/how-to-use-density-argument-to-obtain-inequality?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 2):

No assumptions are needed on $A$ whatsoever  - there exists one unique extension of $A$ to a bounded operator on (say $\tilde{A}$) on $H$ with norm $||\tilde{A}|| \leq C$.

Let $x\in H$ and $x_i \in D$ be such that $x = \lim x_i$.
One checks that the sequence $A x_i$ is Cauchy  since $||A x_i - A x_j|| \leq C ||x_i - x_j|| \to 0$ if $i, j$ are large enough (recall that any convergent sequence is Cauchy). Hence the sequence $A x_i$ converges and we set $\tilde{A}(x) := \lim A x_i$.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. How can I make a link between your answer and the negative answers in this post  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361381/how-to-use-density-argument-to-obtain-inequality?r=SearchResults

Comment: No worries. For the record, the pathological issues in the post you linked to comes from the fact that the spaces are not complete, hence Cauchy sequences may not converge.

Comment: Thank you sir for all the answers

Comment: Good spot.  Well, one should be precise here. There is only one bounded extension of $A$, but there may be more unbounded extensions.

Comment: The example from MathOverflow cited in the reply seems like the clearest. An unbounded functional $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ has dense kernel but is not bounded. There is only one bounded functional which agrees with $f$ on $Ker(f)$ - the zero functional